# Calling action from jquery correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've never used ajax  and I'm just try to see if this will call the method from my controller and give me the desired result. The javascript debugger in VS doesn't seem to be working at the moment. Does this look right?

```
 $("form").submit(function() {
            var hasCurrentJob = $.ajax({
                url: 'Application/HasJobInProgess/@Model.ClientId'
            });
  });
```

controller method

```
public Boolean HasJobInProgress(int clientId)
{
    return _proxy.GetJobInProgress(clientId).Equals(0);
}
```

***Update***

```
$("#saveButton").click(function() {
        var hasCurrentJob = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgress","ClientChoices")/',
            data: { id: @Model.ClientId },
            success: function(data){
                hasCurrentJob = data;
            }
            });
        if (hasCurrentJob) {
            alert("The current clients has a job in progress. No changes can be saved until current job completes");
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use the `Url.Action` HTML Helper method when calling an action method. This will get you the correct url to the action method. You dont need to worry about how many ../ to add/

```
$(function(){
   $("form").submit(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("HasJobInProgess","Application")',
        data: {clientId: '@Model.ClientId'},
       success: function(data) {
        //you have your result from action method here in data variable. do whatever you want with that.
        alert(data);
       }
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that the name of the data values should match the parameters in the action. So to match atbyrds action, it should be data {clientId : ...}

Comment: @atbyrd: Nope. I added alert to just show the result so that you realize that you got the result. You really don't need that. you can use the data variable value for your use

Comment: @Shyju ok I am still getting some 'expected , errors'. will post updated code above in case I missed something;

Comment: @Shyju getting scary error :).   An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in ClientSelection.Core.dll

Comment: @atbyrd: You have some error in your code.Use Visual studio breakpoints and Run in Debug mdoe  to see where you are getting that.